# Spatie Media Library Config Values Are Null

Tags: php

I am having an issue with **Spatie/media-library** , whenever I try to get a value form media-library config file i got **NULL**, for example if run
 
`dd(config('medialibrary.max_file_size'))`
 i got null and if I tried to upload a file i always got **File Is Too Big exception.**

I don't know why is it something wrong with the installation , it is not the first time i user spatie/media-library.

 I have laravel installed with v:6.0
media-library v:7.14.0

Comment: Did you publish the config file and are there actually values in it?

Comment: @kerbholz yes i did and it has all values

Comment: (Btw, you're missing a closing `'` there, but I guess that's a typo) Try running `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan config:clear` to re-read the config

Comment: @kerbholz I ran `composer dumpautoload` and `php artisan config:clear` with no luck , is there any instruction to clear the cache for medialibrary configurations?

Comment: Hmm, strange. You could cache the config and see if the values appear in the cached version: run `php artisan config:cache` which generates the file `bootstrap/cache/config.php`, view that file and see if medialibrary exists there. If not ... try removing/reinstalling the package. Other than that I can't help, sorry